Show that a function is weakly differentiable
Let $\Omega$ be a smooth domain with dimension $N$. Suppose $u \in H_0^{1}(\Omega) \cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. How to show that the function
$$ v (x)= [(1 + |u(x)|)^{-1/4}-1]\mathrm{sgn} (u(x))$$
is weakly differentiable?
For the context, I'm reading the book Elliptic Partial Differential Equations by Gisella Croce and Lucio Boccardo. In Section 11.2, the authors choose the test function $v$ as above, for which I have difficulty proving that $v$ belongs to some Sobolev spaces. Below is an excerpt from the book:
Boccardo, Croce

This function seems to be continuously differentiable. So there should be no problem proving weak differentiability?

Thanks to @daw's hint, below is the answer to the question.
The function $f(x) = [(1+ |x|)^{-1/4}-1] \mathrm{sgn} (x)$ is in
$C^1(\mathbb{R})$. To see this heuristically, one can Taylor $(1+
|x|)^{-1/4}-1 = Cx + O(x^2)$, for some constant $C$. The term $Cx$
compensates the bad discontinuity of $\mathrm{sgn}(x)$ under
differentiation.
Since $v = [(1+ |u|)^{-1/4}-1] \mathrm{sgn} (u) = f (u)$, we can apply
the Chain Rule to obtain $v$ is weakly differentiable (see. e.g., Lemma
2.1 in https://math.aalto.fi/~jkkinnun/files/sobolev_spaces.pdf).
